# How can I print a value only when the row in mySQL database is not empty?

Tags: mysql

I want to echo `Name:` if the row `name` in my SQL table is not empty.
I am a little bit confused, because something else happens then what I am expecting. This is my code:

```
if ($row['name'] != 0 ) echo 'Name: '; 
echo($row['name']);
```

So if the name in my SQL row is Fred, it should print `Name:Fred`, and if the row in my SQL table is empty it should print out nothing. Print out nothing is working fine, but when the name in my row is `Fred` it prints out only `Fred`. But if the name in my row is `1Fred` it prints out `Name:1Fred`. So my code is only working, when a number is inside the name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use brackets, no matter what you see in other developers code. For testing whether a variable is empty or not, use the `empty()` command.

```
if (empty($row['name']) == true) {
     echo 'This is empty';
} else {
     echo 'This is not empty';
}
```

*EDIT:* There is this comparison table that shows the difference between `empty()`, `null` and `isset()`: [Comparison](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
if ($row['name'] != 0 ) {
  echo 'Name: '; 
  echo($row['name']);
}
```

What did you do wrong:
After a condition you can either have one statement (in your case: `echo 'Name: ';`, or you have a list of statements that then need to be enclosed in curly bracers.
Otherwise, your computer ahs no way of knowing when the conditional statements end.